# Is Ariana Dumbledore's death different in the movies compared to the books?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, fantastic-beasts, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

I can't find any mention of this in '[Behind the scenes](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ariana_Dumbledore#Behind_the_scenes)' in the HP fandom.

What I understand is:

1. In books: There was a 3-way duel (or [2v1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGHBwk0quxs) ?) and then Ariana was caught in the cross fire. More info here: [What exactly happened to Ariana when Dumbledore and Grindelwald fought?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133295/what-exactly-happened-to-ariana-when-dumbledore-and-grindelwald-fought)
2. In movies, specifically *Fantastic Beasts 3: The Secrets of Dumbledore*: Albus and Grindelwald planned to run away together. Aberforth didn't approve. Both Albus and Aberforth drew their wands, and Grindelwald laughed.

Or perhaps they're actually the same:

Grindelwald still pulls out a wand. And in the movie version, Albus just omits mention of the other details like how Grindelwald used Cruciatus curse on Aberforth.

Comment: why is there an edit war about the completely ungrammatical and unpronounceable "h wand"?

Comment: @user253751 heteronormative society?

Comment: It's a 1v1v1 duel. or a 4 person duel, if you add Ariana. Everyone for themselves.